# 'non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member' with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

So I tried to create a thread for two functions from a class that I made:

```
MessagesSender all;
    std::thread t1(all.updateMessages);
    std::thread t2(all.sendMessages);
```

But it says this error when I try to compile : 
non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Why??

Comment: [mcve] would be helpful.  I suspect you have a bug in MessagesSender.

Answer (score 1):

you should be doing

```
std::thread t1(&MessagesSender::updateMessages, MessagesSender());
...
...
t1.join();
```

and likewise for any other member functions

If you want to be using the same object then pass the object by reference

```
std::thread t1(&MessagesSender::updateMessages, std::ref(myMessageSenderobj));
```

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Indeed, plus the current code is undefined behaviour as the temporary will be destroyed immediately.

Comment: I have to use an object in the two of them with the same data..

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Arthur Tacca I don't agree that it would be undefined behavior. The arguments to the thread constructor are copied.

Comment: Oops you are right, my mistake. Thanks for clarifying. (Actually it moves if it's an rvalue reference, as it is in this case, but the point is the same: it is instantiating am fresh object target than taking a reference to an existing one.)

Answer (score 0):

`thread` constructors:

```
thread( thread&& other ) noexcept;

template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );

thread(const thread&) = delete;
```

So:

```
... t1(&MessagesSender::updateMessages ...
```